# The best Lock for concurrency: one WRITE and infinite number of READ

Tags: java, concurrency, locks

Is there any Lock in Java that would allow me to do this?

- one WRITE operation at the time
- infinite number of READ operations (even if there ***is*** a WRITE lock acquired)
- optional but great: lock timeout - release lock after a while to avoid deadlock forever

Comment: ... It's called a lock on write, and no lock on read?

Comment: @Xymostech yes, but still the read operation has to be able to continue even if there is already a write lock acquired

Comment: I don't see why a write lock would prevent reads from happening. If you simply don't request a lock when you do a read, nothing will stop you...

Comment: ReentrantReadWriteLock ?

Comment: @Xymostech now I understand what you meant and you're right... What about the optional thing - the timeout. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not really sure it makes sense to have a lock that automatically unlocks (because then you could end up with multiple processes writing at the same time), but you can use a timeout on acquiring a lock, such as using the `tryLock` function of [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there is no circumstance under which reads cannot occur. Do you really need a read lock? If not, then you should just be able to use a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) with 1 permit to protect the write permission. If you still want to track how many reads are happening without the ability to prevent any, you can always count how many reads are in flight with an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: You're right. I don't need a read lock. But Semaphore looks like it's not able to release permits after a timeout.

Comment: @Tomas I know of many locks that can timeout during the acquire phase, but I don't know of any that automatically release themselves after being acquired. You'd probably need to write something custom for that, but I feel I should strongly caution against that. If you have a task that runs longer than the timeout, you *will* have data corruption in the presence of multiple writers. To avoid deadlock, I think you're better off watching for a no-progress state and then [interrupting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) tasks if it happens.